# emacs evil-mode key map

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

yep I am the one who started to use EMACS but not willing to abandon the VIM skills I learned.

evil is definitely a good thing.

the issue I am encountering is that there too few documentation for this. Obviously I am using a tiny fraction of the key-mappings defined in evil.

So I take a look at the evil-maps.el, and get quite a few question regarding this file:

1. a lot of the key are not mapped to the function defined there
2. what is the evil-window-map ? **(just find out my self, it is key-bindings for jumping between windows, and to activate it: need to (setq evil-want-C-w-in-emacs-state 1 ) )**
3. what is the operator pending state ?

did evil load all the maps it listed in the evil-maps file into Emacs ?

any better documentation for evil ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it takes sometime to understand the STATE of EVIL plugin and then those shortkeys just become handy. so the solution is to read the documentation again and again.